# Building Apps using xcodebuild that depend on CocoaLumberjack installed via SPM

Tags: xcode, cocoalumberjack

I'm trying to automate the build of a project that depends on CocoaLumberjack that was installed using Swift Package Manager (SPM). The project builds fine in Xcode (12.5.1 and 13), but fails when building in terminal using `xcodebuild`. I get an error complaining that the `module map` isn't found. I've created two new projects, one swift, and one objective-c to replicate the issue. In both cases, things work great from Xcode, but fail on the command line.

Objective-C Error:

```
fatal error: module map file '/Users/XXX/Development/git/TestAppObjC/build/GeneratedModuleMaps/CocoaLumberjack.modulemap' not found
```

Swift Error:

```
<unknown>:0: error: module map file '/Users/XXX/Development/git/TestAppSwift/build/GeneratedModuleMaps/CocoaLumberjackSwiftSupport.modulemap' not found
<unknown>:0: error: module map file '/Users/XXX/Development/git/TestAppSwift/build/GeneratedModuleMaps/CocoaLumberjack.modulemap' not found
```

The exact command that I'm running:

```
xcodebuild clean build
```

Sample Projects:

[Objective-C Test App](https://github.com/jragingfury/TestAppObjC)

[Swift Test App](https://github.com/jragingfury/TestAppSwift)

Comment: any luck @jragingfury? feel like this could be due to xcodebuild searching for built spm modules in the wrong location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing `derivedDataPath` to `xcodebuild` appears to resolve the issue.

You can find the 'Derived Data' path in Xcode preferences.

In my case:

```
xcodebuild -scheme TestAppSwift -derivedDataPath /Users/mt/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
```

Successful build:

```
note: Build preparation complete
note: Building targets in dependency order
** BUILD SUCCEEDED ** [0.132 sec]
```

[image]

Comment: Note that `scheme` is required when passing `derivedDataPath`: `xcodebuild: error: The flag -scheme, -testProductsPath, or -xctestrun is required when specifying -derivedDataPath.`

Comment: alternative is to pass `clonedSourcePackagesDirPath`